# Angularjs situations where something doesn't work without timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I've come to few situations in angularjs where only timeout solves the problem. I'd really like to understand why this happens and how to solve this.

Examples:

```
opLibrary.directive('opClick', function($parse, $location, $timeout, opDebug) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var action = attrs.opClick.substring(0, 1) == '/' ? attrs.opClick : $parse(attrs.opClick);
        var event = opDebug.desktop ? 'mousedown' : 'touchstart';
        element.bind(event, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $timeout(function() {
                if (angular.isFunction(action)) action(scope);
                else $location.path(action);
            }, 0);
        });
    }
});
```

without timeout $location.path just doesn't trigger

```
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxx',
    });

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.fbInitComplete = true;
    }, 0);
});
```

without timeout view is not updated based on fbInitComplete change, though it updates just before view change as if value of the variable did change, but scope did not catch it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$scope.apply` instead of timeout:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    if (angular.isFunction(action)) action(scope);
    else $location.path(action);
});
```

Reason: You must notify angular when something is done asynchronously, for example when performing ajax call (`$http` does `$scope.$apply` for you).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains everything :)